# Vanier College Practice test - Prove that $\log_{\frac {1} {\sqrt b} }\sqrt x= -\log_b x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, logarithms, exponentiation

Source : Colorado.edu, Vanier College, Worksheet Logarithm Function, Question 8 (https://math.colorado.edu/math1300/resources/Exercises_LogarithmicFunction.pdf)

To be proved :

$\log_{\frac {1} {\sqrt b} }\sqrt x= -\log_b x$.

What I did, before getting stuck :

$n=\log_{\frac {1} {\sqrt b} }\sqrt x$

$\iff \bigg (\frac {1} {\sqrt b} \bigg)^n = \sqrt x $

$\iff \frac {n} { (\sqrt b)^n}= \sqrt x$

$\iff n = (\sqrt b)^n \sqrt x$

Whith the help of @jjagmath I continue the proof at the point I made a mistake :

$ \frac {1} {(\sqrt b)^n}= \sqrt x $

$ \iff 1 = \sqrt x (\sqrt b)^n$

$\iff \frac {1} {\sqrt x} = (\sqrt b)^n$

$ \iff x^{-1/2}= (\sqrt b)^n$

$ \iff n = \log_{\sqrt b} x^{- \frac {1} {2} }$

$ \iff n = - \frac {1} {2}\log_{\sqrt b} x$

$\iff n =  - \frac {1}{2} \frac {\log_b x} {\log_b b^{1/2}}$ $\space \space \space$  by theChange of base formula.

$\iff n =  - \frac {1}{2} \frac {\log_b x} {\frac {1} {2}}$

$ \iff n = - \log_b x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got stuck because you made a mistake: $\left(\frac {1} {\sqrt b} \right)^n \ne \frac {n} { (\sqrt b)^n}$

Your proof should go like this:

$n=\log_{\frac {1} {\sqrt b} }\sqrt x$

$\iff \left(\frac {1} {\sqrt b} \right)^n = \sqrt x $

$\iff \frac {1} { (\sqrt b)^n}= \sqrt x$

$\iff 1 = (\sqrt b)^n \sqrt x$

Can you finish your proof now?

Edit:

I see you finished your proof, but you did something more complicated.
Your proof was almost done like this.

$\iff 1 = (\sqrt b)^n \sqrt x$

$\iff 1 = b^n x$

$\iff b^n = x^{-1}$

$\iff n = \log_b(x^{-1}) = -\log_b(x)$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out !

Comment: I'm trying to finish it :)

Comment: Proof finished, thanks again!

Comment: @VinceVickler You're welcome. Are you going to accept my answer?

Comment: @VinceVickler I completed your proof in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\log_{\frac {1} {\sqrt b} }\sqrt x= -\log_\sqrt b \sqrt x=-\frac{\ln \sqrt x}{\ln \sqrt b}$

Comment: Which rule do you apply in the first step?

Comment: It comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm from conversion between logarithms of arbitrary base. Silent down voter is welcome to express critique, if have any.

Comment: thanks for the source !  and also downvoter $\neq$  me

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\log_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}}{\sqrt{x}} &= \frac{\log{\sqrt{x}}}{\log{\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}}}\\
&= \frac{\log{\sqrt{x}}}{-\log{{\sqrt{b}}}} \\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{2}\log{{x}}}{-\frac{1}{2}\log{{{b}}}} \\
&= -\frac{\log{x}}{\log{b}} \\
&= -\log_b{x}
\end{align}

In total we use the following two rules:
\begin{align}
\log_ab &= \frac{\log{a}}{\log{b}}, \\
\log{(a^{c})} &= c\log{a}.
\end{align}

Comment: @Kolja . No problem, and thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

There is only one logarithm rule you need to know, and that is the definition of logarithm:

$$\log_b x = y \iff b^y = x. \tag{1}$$

In other words, the base-$b$ real-valued logarithm of a positive number $x$ is an *exponent* $y$, to which the base $b$ is raised to yield $x$.  So for instance,

$$\log_3 81 = 4 \iff 3^4 = 81.$$

So if $$\log_{1/\sqrt{b}} \sqrt{x} = y, \tag{2}$$ then $$\left(1/\sqrt{b}\right)^y = \sqrt{x}.$$  But this is the same as writing

$$(b^{-1/2})^y = x^{1/2},$$

or $$b^{-y} = x.$$

Now apply the definition of logarithm again:

$$b^{-y} = x \iff \log_b x = -y. \tag{3}$$

Now we combine Equations $(2)$ and $(3)$:

$$\log_{1/\sqrt{b}} \sqrt{x} = y = -\log_b x,$$

and we are done.

While it may be convenient to use other formulas like the "change of base" formula or $\log_b x^m = m \log_b x$, in actuality these other formulas all follow from the original definition $(1)$.

Comment: Really nice, thanks!  Simplicity is the privilege of masters of art!